# Postgres query runs on Windows but not Linux

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM readings a 
  left join lateral (
     select distinct on (meterno) o.* 
     from offsets o 
     where a.datetime > o.timedate 
     order by o.meterno, o.timedate desc
  ) b ON a.MeterNum = b.MeterNo 
WHERE a.meternum = 3 
  AND a.LynxKey = 8 
ORDER BY a.DateTime DESC
```

This query runs on PostgreSQL 11.11 on Windows, but fails on PostgreSQL 9.2.24 running on a Linux web host.  The hosting company is not anxious to upgrade Postgres. Is there a change to the query that could make it run on both versions?

Comment: `lateral` joins were introduced in Postgres 9.3 and are not available in your unsupported Postgres version. Postgres 9.2 has been [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and unmaintained for nearly 5 years now and shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: I wouldn't do business with such a hosting company.